# jQuery find() method not working in AngularJS directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am having trouble with angularjs directives finding child DOM elements with the injected angular element.

For example I have a directive like so:

```js
myApp.directive('test', function () {
    return {
        restrict: "A",
        link: function (scope, elm, attr) {
            var look = elm.find('#findme');
             elm.addClass("addedClass");
            console.log(look);
        }
    };
});
```

and HTML such as :

```html
<div ng-app="myApp">
    <div test>TEST Div
        <div id="findme"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I have access to the element which is proffed by adding a class to it.
However attempting to access a child element produces an empty array in the var look.

[JSFiddle demo is here](http://jsfiddle.net/raygarner/FZGKA/7/).

Why is something so trivial not working properly?

Answer (score 76, accepted):

From the [docs on `angular.element`](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/angular.element):

> `find()` - Limited to lookups by tag name

So if you're not using jQuery with Angular, but relying upon its jqlite implementation, you can't do `elm.find('#someid')`.

You do have access to `children()`, `contents()`, and `data()` implementations, so you can usually find a way around it.

Comment: Thanks.  In my case i was actually including JQuery, however it was being included after angularjs which is apparently what the problem is.  
Also I did not recognize that find was not available in JQlite it does not specify that in the docs! Just says "Limited to lookups by tag name" which I thought meant id tag name?

Comment: So to clarify the fix for me was move the <script src="jquery"> tag above the angular <script src="angular"> tag.

Comment: Last bit of clarification 
You can see here what I had to do to get this to work in jsfiddle.
I had to import jquery first then added angularjs as a resource to get it to work.
Non-working rev: [link](http://jsfiddle.net/raygarner/FZGKA/7/)
working rev: [link](http://jsfiddle.net/raygarner/FZGKA/8/)

Comment: I used jQuery(elm).find('#someid')

Answer (score 27):

You can easily solve that in 2 steps:

1- Reach the child element using querySelector like that:
`var target = element[0].querySelector('tbody tr:first-child td')`

2- Transform it to an `angular.element` object again by doing:
`var targetElement = angular.element(target)`

You will then have access to all expected methods on the `targetElement` variable.

Comment: This should be the accepted anwser. It doesn't use jQuery and does not impose the element we want to find has an ID.

Answer (score 13):

Before the days of jQuery you would use:

```
   document.getElementById('findmebyid');
```

If this one line will save you an entire jQuery library, it might be worth while using it instead.

For those concerned about performance:
Beginning your selector with an ID is always best as it uses native function document.getElementById.

```
// Fast:
$( "#container div.robotarm" );

// Super-fast:
$( "#container" ).find( "div.robotarm" );
```

http://learn.jquery.com/performance/optimize-selectors/

jsPerf
http://jsperf.com/jquery-selector-benchmark/32

Comment: This is BAD! getElementById will search the entire HTML document beginning from the root, and is not restricted to search in the template

Comment: i find `var $el = $('div.robotarm', '#container');` more readable given the context.

Comment: @Spock maybe you could use jsPerf to demonstratet? getElementById is internally indexed, so it doesn't scan the DOM.

Comment: @Spock Care to share how one should do it?

Comment: @Karl > I think I was wrong. getElementByID speed does not get affected by this, if you specifically search for an ID.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying @Spock, it will help others too. Nice to see a humble person on here.

Answer (score 9):

`find()` - Limited to lookups by tag name
you can see more information 
https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.element

Also you can access by name or id or call please following example:

```
angular.element(document.querySelector('#txtName')).attr('class', 'error');
```

Answer (score 1):

I used

```
elm.children('.class-name-or-whatever')
```

to get children of the current element

Comment: jqLite does not accept a selector for children(), you just get all the direct child elements.

Answer (score -2):

If anyone is looking to grab the scope off of a 'controller as' element,.. something like this:

```
<div id="firstctrl" ng-controller="firstCtrl as vm">
```

use the following:

```
var vm = angular.element(document.querySelector('#firstctrl')).scope().vm;
```

Comment: Not sure how this is relevant. Can't see any mention about getting child scope or controllerAs syntax. Might have missed something and happy to be proven wrong.

Answer (score -3):

You can do it like this:

```
 var myApp = angular.module('myApp', [])
  .controller('Ctrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {
     $scope.aaa = 3432
 }])
 .directive('test', function () {
    return {
       link: function (scope, elm, attr) {
           var look = elm.children('#findme').addClass("addedclass");
           console.log(look);
        }
   };
});

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="Ctrl">
   <div test>TEST Div
      <div id="findme">{{aaa}}</div>
   </div>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/FZGKA/133/

Comment: This one doesn't work as you might expect: http://jsfiddle.net/FZGKA/167/ it's just adding the class to all children, the selector doesn't matter